# Akka HTTP: Retrieve ByteString from Directive1[String]

Tags: scala, akka-http

I have barely started scala and trying to write small project.
I wrote server which consumes graphql requests. For now I have a problem with jwt tokens, because method used for validation returns Directive1[ByteString] instead of ByteString.
Can I retrieve it somehow? I need claim data from that jwt token after validation

Here is the code that I'm struggling with:

```
val directive: Directive1[ByteString] = jwt.jwtAuthenticate(Unmarshaller._fromStringUnmarshallerFromByteStringUnmarshaller)
val claim: String = ???
```

Comment: Hello @TomerShetah. The problem is not with converting. It's really easy to use byteString.utf8String method, but I am struggling with converting from Directive1[ByteString] to ByteString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in [Akka Http Dirrective docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/index.html) - directive is building block of route. So you need to handle route, something like:

```
val claim: String = dirrective { claim: String => // your token string
  complete((StatusCodes.Ok, "Handled")) // give HTTP response
}
```

Comment: I have tried to do so according to docs, but it will return not a string but a server. Route. I don't need a route there, just a string with a claim

Comment: @RomanLeshchenko I'm afraid I'm not following you. You can't use `Dirrective` outside Akka Http Route infrastructure - it is supposed to be built in route which handles incoming HTTP requests eventually. What are you using to handle requests?

Comment: Here is a brief overview of what I'm doing:

I have a graphql schema build with Caliban. Some queries and mutations must not be available to perform without JWT token. The problem is that I can't perform authentication in routes like:

 (post & path("api" / "graphql")) {
 jwtAuthenticate { claim =>
...

I can't perform it this way because it will prevent introspection(schema discovery) requests. So I am trying to validate the token in another place, but looks like it won't work that way

Comment: @RomanLeshchenko why not you can - just check if `Authorization` header exists and then invoke `jwtAuthenticate ` otherwise proceed to another branch execution which does not require authentication.

Comment: @RomanLeshchenko - see https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/header-directives/optionalHeaderValue.html

Comment: unfortunately, can't be done, because Caliban's graphql interpreter can't handle introspection requests. I think as a hotfix a can either parse the request body if it is an introspection query and there is no jwt - let it pass. What do you think?
Another solution - to use another jwt library so I'll be able to  validate jwt in my middleware class

Comment: @RomanLeshchenko Well, I'm not much GraphQL expert honestly, I'd try to find alternative library which fits better your requirements of optional authentication first - and then think about parsing. If my answer was somehow helpful, please, don't forgot to hit +1 or accept it. Thanks!